# Selenium + Python: check attribute value

Tags: python, selenium, web, attributes, styles

I want to check the value of an attribute that is present in an element.

I have the following Python code:

```
validkey = False

# Was the key valid.
element = w.find_element_by_id('registerkey_form')

# Is the activation message is shown, meaning it was successful in activation.

if element.get_attribute('style'):

    validkey = True
```

The problem is the second last line.
I want to check for:

```
style="display:block;"
```

not just the existence of style itself but the value as well.

Originally it is:

```
style="display:none;"
```

I want to check if it is "block".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to check value of `style` attribute, try

```
if element.get_attribute('style') == 'display: block;':
    validkey = True
```

or better to do it as below:

```
if element.value_of_css_property('display') == 'block':
    validkey = True
```

Comment: Thank you, the 2nd suggestion worked nicely.
It would have taken me a while to figure out that it was this sort of syntax `('display') == 'block'`. Python is very different to C languages.

Comment: @RvBVakama , yeah, each language has some specifics. AFAIK in JavaScript it's also would be `('display') == 'block'`... but there is also `('display') === 'block'` which really makes me scared :))